# setText causing a crash

Tags: java, android

For the better part of every day for the past week, I have been working on this project of controlling a textfield with the input of a potentiometer, and my setText command keeps crashing the program. I'm tired of tinkering and debugging but getting very little accomplished, and I need some help badly.

If you need to see all of the projects files, I can upload them as well.

Search for "This line causes a crash"

```
package edu.uidaho.pong;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameThread extends Thread {


    /** Handle to the surface manager object we interact with */
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Paint _paint;
    private GameState _state;
    public PongActivity _pong;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
            Handler handler) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _paint = new Paint();
        _state = new GameState();
        _pong = new PongActivity();

    }

//  @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Canvas canvas = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            _state.update(_pong);
            _state.draw(canvas, _paint);
            _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


            int ret = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int i;

            int tempdebug = 0;
            //while (true) { // read data
            while (tempdebug++ < 10){
//              try {
//                  ret = _pong.mInputStream.read(buffer);
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  break;
//              }
                ret = 5; // let's pretend there's a 5 every time since I can't test the usb

                i = 0;
                while (i < ret) {
                    int len = ret - i;
                    if (len >= 1) {
                        Message m = Message.obtain(_pong.mHandler);
                        int value = (int)buffer[i];
                        // 'f' is the flag, use for your own logic
                        // value is the value from the arduino
                        m.obj = new ValueMsg('f', value);
                        _pong.mHandler.sendMessage(m);
                    }
                    i += 1; // number of bytes sent from arduino
                }
            }
            //_pong.mResponseField.setText("Reading: "); This line causes a crash

        }
    }

    public GameState getGameState() {
        return _state;
    }
}
```

Logcat output -

```
03-03 22:45:49.639: W/dalvikvm(381): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-03 22:45:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
03-03 22:45:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 22:45:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at edu.uidaho.pong.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:70)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at edu.uidaho.pong.GameView.surfaceDestroyed(GameView.java:46)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:587)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:481)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:213)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:4027)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:782)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 22:45:50.189: E/global(381):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: mResponseField is something that you implemented ? it's not a member of Activity class. Add a debug printing in the constructor of PongActivity - make sure it has been initialized.

Comment: How do you add a debug printing? I tried toasting, but ran into issues of not being able to toast from a thread.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say exactly since there is no logcat, but this is probably happening because you're trying to change your `TextView` from a separate thread, which is prohibited in Android. One of the solutions to this problem is to put a reference to your `Activity` inside the class that runs a separate thread and place any `View` changing code inside the `Activity.runOnUiThread()` method, which takes a `Runnable` as the argument. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

```
_pong.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                _pong.mResponseField.setText("Reading: ");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm not sure how follow your suggestion.

Right I am changing TextView from a separate thread. So how do I create this reference to my activity? I have an object instance I am calling currently. I don't want this because it's being called on another thread? "_pong.mHandler.sendMessage(m);"

If you could direct me to an example that would be helpful. I wasn't able to create the necessary code from the development site. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

So "runOnUiThread (_pong.mHandler.sendMessage(m);)" ?

Comment: I put this code into my game thread class "public class GameThread extends Thread"'s public void run() function.

So my code looks like `public void run(){
//...
your code snippet here
//...
}`
I am getting an error "The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: @user1018733, I meant you should replace this code: _pong.mResponseField.setText("Reading: "); with the snippet I've provided.

Comment: Right I did that. Would you by chance be willing to walk me through on team viewer or a similar program for about 30 minutes? I'd pay you $20 on paypal if you could fix or explain how to fix what is going on. The total project is about 500 LoC, but the price is negotiable if it's not an easy fix.

Comment: @user1018733, Sorry, can't do that. I don't have PayPal btw.